# How to setup wireless printing from a printer connected via usb on Ubuntu Server 12.10?

Tags: wireless, networking, server, printing

today I have setup a basic home server for my family. So far, we have FTP set up, so we can backup all our files. Is it possible to setup wireless printing (printer is connected to server via usb)? We all have Windows, except for the server of course.

Please help. Also i'd be great to make a noob friendly guide, i'm not very good with Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are (at least) two possible ways.

The easiest is to simply share your printer via CUPS. To do this, open the printer dialogue (system menu -> printers) and right click on the printer. Make sure that the checkbox "Share this printer" is checked. Now you are done on your Linux box.

On how to set up printing to IPP using Windows 7, read this guide:
https://superuser.com/questions/300986/ipp-printing-from-windows-7-ultimate

Use the generic postscript driver for the printer in Windows, conversion from postscript to the printers native format is done by the printer driver installed on ubuntu.

The second, much more complicated way is to set up [SAMBA](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu) sharing.

Comment: It's an ubuntu server, it doesn't have GUI. :/

Comment: Nevermind, found this. Thanks anyway :)
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=928719