# log in to cups admin in browser?

Tags: wireless, printing, cups-lpd

I want to use a wireless printer.  I googled it and it said to go to website: 127.0.0.1:631/ and click on admin.  It asks me to log in.  I put in my ubuntu name and password and get denied.  Does anybody know who owns this website so I can request a password?  Is it owned by Canonical?

Answer (score 0):

That web address (127.0.0.1) is for the CUPS printer control panel on your own computer, it is not a real website.

You shouldn't need to do that in Ubuntu. You should be able to set it up from the system settings GUI, by just entering the printer's IP address when asked.

More details, including screenshots:

[How to connect to a WLAN printer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345104/how-to-connect-to-a-wlan-printer)

Answer (score 0):

It should be expecting your own regular username and password, but your user account must belong to the `lpadmin` group in order to perform printer administrative tasks - you can check by opening a terminal window and typing

```
id -Gn
```

If the group 'lpadmin' is not listed in the output, add the user with

```
sudo gpasswd --add $USER lpadmin
```

then log out and back in for the change to take effect.